# Apollo+React: How do I use a proxy so client and graphql are on the same domain?

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am following an (excellent) security tutorial by Ryan Chenkie, but trying to use a graphql api rather than a REST api which he uses.

The **graphql server is running on localhost:4000** and the **Apollo-React client is on localhost:3000**. It works fine.

Now, I want to use a cookie for the auth token, so I need client and server to be on the same domain.
Per Chenkie's recommendation I set up a proxy on the client in package.json

`"proxy": "http://localhost:4000/"`

then in my index.js, where apollo client is set up, I create an httplink as follows:

```
const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:3000", 
  headers: { authorization: token },  // The token in the auth header will be removed when the cookie approach is working)
});
```

For the uri I have tried the following:

```
  uri: "http://localhost:3000"
  uri: "/graphql"
  uri: "/"
  uri: ""
```

I always get a 404 error.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Dumb mistake on my part.
**Solution**:  ***You must manually stop and restart the client-side react server for the proxy to take effect.  Just saving a file is not sufficient.***

Also, the HttpLink `uri: "/graphql"` is the correct one.  It works as expected (when you restart the react server!)

Answer (score 0):

In the proxy section in your `package.json` you have to add the base url of the server that you want to proxy, in your case the GraphQL server aka `http://localhost:4000`.

When creating the link, add the endpoint under which GraphQL accepts the requests, usually that is `/graphql` but you'll have to make sure.

So that'd be:

```js
const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: "/graphql", 
  headers: { authorization: token },  // The token in the auth header will be removed when the cookie approach is working)
});
```

This means that every relative request will be proxied towards `localhost:4000` and for your HTTPLink that it will use `http://localhost:4000/graphql`.

If you still get the 404 make sure that your graphql server is running and that the graphql endpoint is indeed `/graphql`.

Comment: Thanks Philip, but I think I had already done this as described in my question.  For the uri I tried several different strings including "/graphql" (see above) but none work.  Any further thoughts?  (Server is running.  I dont know how to verify the endpoint is /graphql)